# Counting the number of words in string?

Tags: python

I have written this function.

```
# Function to count words in a string.
def word_count(string):
    tokens = string.split()
    n_tokens = len(tokens)
    print (n_tokens)

# Test the code.
print(word_count("Hello World!"))
print(word_count("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."))
```

but the output is

```
2
None
9 
None
```

instead of just

```
2
9
```

Comment: return n_tokens rather than printing it

Comment: You print your result in the function, but it returns None since you don't return anything from it

Comment: ive fixed it. salutations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word_count` does not have a `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `None`. Your function prints the number of tokens `print (n_tokens)` and then your function call `print(word_count("Hello World!"))` prints `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Brian said, this code illustrates how to get what you want:

```
# Function to count words in a string.
def word_count(string):
    tokens = string.split()
    n_tokens = len(tokens)
    return n_tokens     # <-- here is the difference

print(word_count("Hello World!"))
print(word_count("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."))
```